# google analytics g4 enviar eventos desde php no con fectch de js. es posible?

Tags: google-analytics

Buenos días saludos cordiales, existe alguna forma de hacer esto desde php con algun curl el ejemplo de google esta desde javascripty quisiera hacerlo dsde php enviar mis eventos?
ejemplo convertir a PHP. Muchas gracias

```
const measurementId = `G-XXXXXXXXXX`;
const apiSecret = `<secret_value>`;

fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurementId}&api_secret=${apiSecret}`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "client_id": "client_id",
    "events": [{
      "name": "search",
      "params": {
        "search_term": "t-shirts"
      }
    }]
  })
});
```

Espero puedan ayudarme...